# Validación de formulario del lado del cliente con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

lo que quiero es que NO se envíen los datos al servidor a menos que se seleccione un checkbox. Anteriormente la validación funcionaba correctamente, después de un tiempo dejó de funcionar, no estoy seguro si es un error de sintaxis.

Tengo el siguiente HTML:

```
<form class="form-group" method="post" name="form" onsubmit = "validarCI(event, this);" action="{{ action('ProductoController@store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
 <table class="table" >
    @foreach($costoIndirecto as $ci)
     <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="checkbox" name="ci[]" value="{{$ci['id']}}"> {{$ci['nombre']}} - {{$ci['valor']}} Bs
      </td>
     </tr>

    @endforeach
        </table>  
  </form>
```

y el siguiente código en JavaScript

```
function validarCI(e) {   
var formulario = document.form;
var ci = false;
for (var i = 0; i < formulario.ci.length; i++) {
  if (formulario.ci[i].checked) {
    ci = true;
  }
}

if (!ci){
  alert ('Debe seleccionar al menos un costo indirecto');
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
  e.returnValue = false;
  }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer la validación en lugar de usar `document.form` puedes usar `document.getElementsByName` para obtener los checkbox:

```
var formulario = document.getElementsByName('ci[]');
```

y luego la validación te queda así:

```js
function validarCI(e) {   
  var formulario = document.getElementsByName('ci[]');
  var ci = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < formulario.length; i++) {
    if (formulario[i].checked) {
      ci = true;
    }
  }

  if (!ci){
    alert ('Debe seleccionar al menos un costo indirecto');
    if (e.preventDefault) {
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
    e.returnValue = false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="form-group" method="post" name="form" onsubmit = "validarCI(event, this);" action="{{ action('ProductoController@store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
 <table class="table" >
    @foreach($costoIndirecto as $ci)
     <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="checkbox" name="ci[]" value="{{$ci['id']}}"> {{$ci['nombre']}} - {{$ci['valor']}} Bs
      </td>
     </tr>

    @endforeach
        </table>  
        
        <button >Enviar</button>
        
  </form>
```

Puedes probar que el formulario solo se envia si se marca el checkbox, si no se marca aparecerá el alert.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfectamente

Comment: @AndrésUcero que bien (ノ・∀・)ノ de nada.